# SQL query runs very slow using order by

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, sql-order-by

I have two tables. `uploads` and `profits`.

uploads:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ id ║  name        ║ more columns...  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ ................ ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║ ................ ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║ ................ ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║ ................ ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

profits:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ uploadid ║    amount    ║ more columns...  ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║    1     ║     4.0      ║ ................ ║
║    1     ║     7.2      ║ ................ ║
║    3     ║     6.3      ║ ................ ║
║    4     ║     2.5      ║ ................ ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

As you can see, `uploads`.`id` => `profits`.`uploadid`

I want to display some rows from the `uploads` table with one more column that tells me how many "profits" there are.

Example for result:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ id ║  name        ║  profitsCount  ║ more columns...  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║       2        ║ ................ ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║       0        ║ ................ ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║       1        ║ ................ ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║       1        ║ ................ ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Note: in the real table the `uploads`.`id` and the `profits`.`uploadid` columns are `varchar` and not `int`, I did it here with `int` to be more clear.

The problem is that when I run the query with large tables (thousands of rows) it takes **lots of time**

My query:

```
SELECT          `uploads`.* ,COUNT(`profits`.`uploadid`) AS `numProfits`
FROM            `uploads`
LEFT JOIN       `profits`
ON              `uploads`.`id` = `profits`.`uploadid`
GROUP BY        `uploads`.`id`
ORDER BY        `numProfits`
DESC
LIMIT           30
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on that tables?

Comment: And BTW MySQL allows selecting the complete record when you only group by a single column - but that is just so wrong IMO. :)

Comment: @juergend The `id` column is the primary column. Example for `id`: `OQl1iYdWF`

Comment: and `uploadid` is also indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT u.* ,COUNT(p.uploadid) AS numProfits
FROM uploads LEFT JOIN
     profits p
     ON u.id = p.uploadid
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY numProfits DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

First improvement:  create an index on `profits(uploadid)`.  That will likely solve your problem.  You might be able to get even better performance with:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*) from profits p where u.id = p.uploadid) as numProfits
from uploads u
order by numProfits desc
limit 30;
```

This eliminates the need for the file sort aggregation.  I prefer the first version with the explicit aggregation, but the subquery can work better.

You can also try the aggregation in a subquery:

```
select u.*, numProfits
from uploads u join
     (select uploadid, count(*) as numProfits
      from profits p
      group by uploadid
      order by numProfits desc
      limit 30
     ) p
     on u.id = p.uploadid;
order by numProfits desc;
```

EDIT:

For the last solution, to choose rows even that don't have a profit, use a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select u.*, coalesce(numProfits, 0) as numProfits
from uploads u left join
     (select uploadid, count(*) as numProfits
      from profits p
      group by uploadid
      order by numProfits desc
      limit 30
     ) p
     on u.id = p.uploadid;
order by numProfits desc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! your second query have done the job perfectly.

Comment: I noticed that it chooses only the rows that has profits. How can I choose everything, and if there are no profits, it will write `0` or `null`? (I'm talking about your second query)

Answer (score -2):

You can minimize SQL select query time by indexing the order by field, this could (and will) affect your insert time however (and update whenever the index column is affected)